# mock a dom mouse event with self defined clientx

Tags: javascript, events, dom

I recently want to mock a mouse event in chrome 27 to mock a click. What's more, the event must have clientx.
I do the following coding, but clientX value always be 0, please help me out, thanks.

```
var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
evt.initEvent("click", true, true, window, 1, 800, 600, 290, 260, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
console.log(evt.clientX);
```

Should it be 90 right? The other values remains 0.

Finally got what is wrong:
use **initMouseEvent** instead of initEvent, initEvent is depressed.

Comment: I'm also depressed that you didn't answer your own question.

Comment: initEvent do not init mouse event properly, because it takes 3 simple argments while initMouseEvent handle it correctly. We must use the specific constructor for the specific Event, as say initMouseEvent for MouseEvent

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're right. Anyway, on SO, we love having answers validated by OP. Can you enter your solution below on the *Your Answer* box and validate it if it answers your question?

Comment: I am new to post an answer,Soryy. But i got error here :Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You can answer in 6 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead.

Comment: Mr. C : alright then, wait and answer :-) Good job finding what you came for.

Answer (score 2):

initEvent do not init mouse event properly, because it takes 3 simple argments while initMouseEvent handle it correctly. We must use the specific constructor for the specific Event, as say initMouseEvent for MouseEvent.

```
var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 1, 800, 600, 290, 260, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
console.log(evt.clientX);
```